# subtract two dates in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss using perl

Tags: perl, date, datetime

I have two dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss which I want to find the number of hours between.  These dates are 2020-10-26 12:00:00 and 2020-10-27 18:00:00.

Below is the snippet of code that I use to find the number of hours:

```
use Time::Piece

my $date1 = '2020-10-26 12:00:00';
my $date2 = '2020-10-27 18:00:00';

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my $diff = Time::Piece->strptime($date1,$format) - Time::Piece->strptime($date2,$format);
```

This should give me the time in days which I could easily convert to hours but I get the error:

```
Invalid version format (non-numeric data) at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Exporter/Heavy.pm line 120.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test_diff.pl line 5.
```

How do I tweak the code to get the desired results?

Comment: Missing semicolon on the `use` line.

Answer (score 5):

The `use` line needs a semicolon. Without it, the next line is interpreted as a parameter to the `import` method of [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece).

After adding the semicolon, `$diff` contains the time in seconds, not days.

To get the difference in days, you can

```
use Time::Seconds;
...
my $days = $diff / ONE_DAY;
```

Note that the result might be wrong around daylight saving times changes.